Tricky constraints with MATLAB fmincon in order to plan a trajectory
I am trying to solve a minimum problem on MATLAB.
Let me explain in more detail: it is about a vehicle that can move in two-dimensional space. The simulation starts with the vehicle at a known initial position (which is 10, 0) and from there it has to reach an end point by maximizing (with a certain coefficient) the observability measured by a beacon. This efficiency measure is given by the determinant of the FIM matrix.
Knowing that the model follows a law of the type:

In the first part of the problem, we eliminate the task of reaching the final position since we are initially interested in reducing the uncertainty that the beacon has about the position of the vehicle, so we want to access a better estimate.
This leads to the following optimum problem

Basically, I am looking for the sequence of u control inputs that maximizes the determinant of the FIM matrix at instant K
To do this, I constructed the Aeq matrix and the beq vector to obtain the constraints in the form p(k+1) - p(0) - sum(u(k)) = 0.
I also wrote the nonlinear equality constraints regarding the norm of u.
To arrive at this, the initial guess vector x0 is composed of (4*K)+2 elements (x and y components for K positions + 2 for p0, x and y components for K control inputs).
Now comes the hard part. To move the vehicle to the final position, two constraints are added (take them to be correct) and the problem becomes:
The point is that I cannot figure out how to set these two constraints. Since there are new constraints on the u(k) inputs, do I need to add new rows to the Aeq matrix?
For the last constraint instead should I construct the matrix A for the inequality constraints?
I just don't know how to proceed.
Thank you very much and sorry for the length of the post but I wanted to make sure everything was understandable.
If you want to make an idea on how I reached this point, here it is the code:
K = 40;
n = K+1;
myx = ones(4*K+2, 1);

Aeq = builMatrix(2*K, (4*K+2), (2*n)+1);
beq = zeros((2*K), 1);

new_row1 = zeros(1, (4*K+2));
new_row1(1) = 1;
new_row2 = zeros(1, (4*K+2));
new_row2(2) = 1;

new_row_b1 = 10;
new_row_b2 = 0;

Aeq = [new_row1; new_row2; Aeq];
beq = [new_row_b1; new_row_b2; beq];

options = optimoptions('fmincon', 'MaxFunctionEvaluations', 1e6, 'MaxIterations', 1e6, 'Algorithm', 'interior-point');
    
finalx = fmincon(@(x) detFIM(x), myx, [], [], Aeq, beq, [], [], @(x) nonlinear(x), options);

indici_x = 1:2:2*K+1;

indici_y = 2:2:2*K+2;

x = finalx(indici_x);
y = finalx(indici_y);

plot(x,y);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
title('Trajectory');

function A = buildMatrix(n, m, k)
    A = zeros(n, m);

    for i = 1:2:n-1  
        row = i;     
        col = k;     
        while row <= n && col <= m
            A(row, col) = -1;  
            row = row + 1;    
            col = col + 1;   
        end
    end

    A(1:2:end, 1) = -1;   
    A(2:2:end, 2) = -1;  

    row = 1;   
    col = 3;   
    while row <= n && col <= m
        A(row, col) = 1;  
        row = row + 1;    
        col = col + 1;    
    end
end

function [c, ceq] = nonlinear(x)
    K = 40;
    c = [];
    for i = 1:K
        idx = 2*K + 2*i + 1;  
        ceq(i) = x(idx)^2 + x(idx+1)^2 - 1;
    end
end

function objective = detFIM(x)
    K = 40;
    P0 = (1/0.05^2)*eye(2);
    FIM0 = inv(P0);
    sigma = sqrt(0.05);
    intermediateFIM = 0;
    
    for i = 3:2:(2*K)+2
        intermediateFIM = intermediateFIM + (1/(x(i)^2+x(i+1)^2))*[x(i)^2, x(i)*x(i+1); x(i)*x(i+1), x(i+1)^2];
    end
    almostFIM = intermediateFIM*(1/sigma^2);
    FIM = FIM0 + almostFIM;
    objective = -log(det(FIM));
end

